# Error when trying to lowercase columns in SQL Plus query

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, ora-00904

OK, I am using SQL Plus and I am trying to view the table and one of the columns I was to view in lower case.  This shold be very easy but for some reason it is not work.  The code I am using is

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_ADD (LOWER)CUSTOMER_FIRST, (UPPER)CUSTOMER_LAST
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

The error I am getting is ORA-00904: "CUSTOMER_LAST": invalid identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lower and upper is function call, and you also have a missing coma after CUSTOMER_ADD. proper sql should be

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_ADD, LOWER(CUSTOMER_FIRST), UPPER(CUSTOMER_LAST) FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: OK - That worked - I realize that i was missing the comma but when you submit not much you can do about it.  However I am wondering what I was doing differently.  When i ran the code it was the exact same.  I just copied and pasted yours in.

Answer (score 2):

Try `lower(customer_first)` and  `upper(customer_last)`

Comment: I tried it and I received the same error. I am fairly sure that command is correct but i tried on two different systems and neither is working

Comment: you are missing a comma after `CUSTOMER_ADD`.

Comment: you might want to do a "descr customer" to see the definition of the customer table.